# Translate Animation Issue in Android

Tags: android, text, translate-animation

I am new to Android, I try to make translate animation.

This is my xml code: (**rail.xml**)

```
<translate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="100%p"
 android:toXDelta="0"
 android:duration="4000" />
```

and this is my java code:

```
final Animation animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.rail);
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++ ){

    animShow.setRepeatCount(i);

    textTV.setText("Hello Android!!");
    textTV.startAnimation(animShow);
}
```

I want to ask, how do I change the text of each animation repeat?

Answer (score 2):

Register an `AnimationListener` via `setAnimationListener()`, and change your text in the listener's `onAnimationRepeat()` method.